# How to increase number of viewers?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, bounty

A few days ago I asked a [question about Kakegurui anime episode 3](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/68302/are-kakegurui-compulsive-gambler-episode-3-calculations-correct). The number of viewers was about 20, so I started a bounty on it. While my question is the only question with a bounty in this website, it only got 20 more viewers with just 1 upvote and **no answer and no comment!**

What should I do to attract more people for my question?

Comment: I think if I ask it on Stack Overflow it gets lots of downvotes and closing votes but it has more chance to get some answers or comments related to the anime than this site :))

Comment: Well this type of question would likely be off topic on SO and folks may come after it with a chip in their shoulder. You can try asking this in other chatrooms on Stack Exchange, but make sure they don't have any topic restrictions

Comment: @AliEnt to be honest, this site is considerably quiet, there are not a lot of regulars here. And these regulars may not have seen the series yet, so they don't have any comments either.

Comment: Well, put a bounty to attract attention.